# Как из таблицы MySQL вывести список?

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

В phpMyAdmin создал таблицу, как ее теперь вывести на страницу сайта?

Answer (score 2):

Долго рассказывать. [читайте](http://www.phptown.ru/php/sql_select.php)